# Does Apache Thrift TSimpleServer drop requests?

Tags: thrift

I am doing some research, and sending requests at very high rate (100 requests per second) to an Apache Python `TSimpleServer`. I notice that the client side says that 353 requests are sent to the server, but at the end of the day, the server only receives 345 requests. Does anyone have idea on what goes wrong? I cannot use `TThreadedServer` because the underlying library is not thread-safe, and I just wonder whether `TSimpleServer` drops requests at high rps. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it our. Since the function is declared as `oneway`, the client has to open the transport rather than close it immediately after the function call.